# ASP.net Core 2.0 customer Tag helpers not being able used in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

My project which is in ASP.net Core 2.0. I am trying to create custom tag helper but with no success.

For example, the Tag helper which I have created below is not showing up in intellisense or being rendered in the contact.html.

Help?

EmailTagHelper.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tallog.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("my-email")]
    public class EmailTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private const string EmailDomain = "example.com";

        // Can be passed via <email mail-to="..." />. 
        // Pascal case gets translated into lower-kebab-case.
        public string MailTo { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = "a";    // Replaces <email> with <a> tag

            var address = MailTo + "@" + EmailDomain;
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", "mailto:" + address);
            output.Content.SetContent(address);
        }
    }
}
```

_ViewImports.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Tallog
@using Tallog.Models
@using Tallog.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers"
@addTagHelper "*, Tallog.TagHelpers"
```

Contact.html

```
@{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Contact";
        ViewData["PageTitle"] = "Contact";
    }

    <h3>@ViewData["Message"]</h3>

    <address>
        <strong>Support:</strong><my-email mail-to="Support"></my-email><br />
        <strong>Marketing:</strong><my-email mail-to="Marketing"></my-email>    
    </address>
```

Solution structure
[image]

Comment: Regardless of it appearing in intellisense, does it work? Can you debug it?

Comment: Its not in View's Intellisense at all.

Comment: Updated with solution Structure

Comment: Did you change it to `@addTagHelper "*, Tallog"`, as explained in the marked duplicate?

Comment: Thank you. I did realise it was referring the assembly and not the namespace.

Comment: No problem. It seems to be a somewhat common cause of confusion.